# Getting duplicate class error by migrating from paging 2 to paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging

I'm using Paging library version 2 in my project, and I want to migrate into version 3. Now I'm getting this error: `Duplicate class kotlin.reflect.KClasses found in modules jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.1.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.1) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.3.71.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.71)`

Can anyone knows how can I resolve it?

Comment: assuming you are using gradle, check the dependency tree and figure out which dependency is depending on older version. then exclude `jetified-kotlin-reflect` from that dependency

Comment: Thank you. How can I check the dependency tree?

Comment: I've found dependencies by ./gradlew app:dependencies. But there's a lot and impossible to figure out.